# Javascript onclick redirect to page

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I alter this code to redirect me to any hyperlink.

```
function myDayClickHandler(eventObj) {
    // Get the Date of the day that was clicked from the event object
    var date = eventObj.data.calDayDate;
    // store date in our global js variable for access later
    clickDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
    // open our add event dialog
    $('#add-event-form').dialog('open');
};
```

PS: I need the date and click date variable.

Thanks

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: add `url` as a parameter or a global variable
`window.location = url + "?date=" + date + "&clickDate=" + clickDate`